# Load string resource for textblock x:Uid in code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, xaml, windows-phone

I have a string resource that I'm using to set as the x:uid for a textblock

```
<data name="Expected.Text" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>Expected Text</value>
</data>

<TextBlock x:Name="control" x:uid="Expected />
```

I'm trying to write a Unit test to check if the text is correct. However I can't get a handle on the "Expected" string because it has a .text at the end so that it can be displayed in the TextBlock

```
ResourceLoader loader = ResourceLoader.GetForCurrentView();
var expected = loader.GetString("Expected");
Assert.AreEqual(expected, control.Text);
```

This code fails because var expected is blank

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can access that property via the following notation:

```
var expected = loader.GetString("Expected/Text");
```

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-resources/localize-strings-ui-manifest#refer-to-a-string-resource-identifier-from-code

Comment: Anybody understand why "Expected/Text" instead of "Expected.Text" ?

Comment: Seems like a typo.

Comment: No, no, it's correct. Haven't written any Windows apps in a white, but here is the source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-resources/localize-strings-ui-manifest#refer-to-a-string-resource-identifier-from-code